# How can I initiate an instancetype from Objective-C with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, instancetype

I have an api that I have to translate it from Objective-C to Swift.
I'm stuck with some type of constructor or initialization I don't really know.

This is how the .h file is:

```
+ (instancetype) newProductionInstance;
+ (instancetype) newDemoInstance;
```

This is how .m file is:

```
+ (instancetype) newProductionInstance
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithBaseURLString:productionURL];
}

+ (instancetype) newDemoInstance
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithBaseURLString:demoURL];
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURLString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    if (self = [self init])
    {
        _apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the call that they have to the main file I'm translating:

```
mobileApi = [MobileAPI newDemoInstance];
```

So I want to convert only the last line to Swift 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mobileApi = MobileAPI.newDemoInstance()
```

or

```
let mobileApi = MobileAPI.newDemoInstance()
```

if you don't intend to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

It simply `MobileAPI.newDemoInstance()`.

```
let mobileApi = MobileAPI.newDemoInstance()
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to import `MobileAPI.h` in `Bridging-Header.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
 class YourClass: NSObject {
    //Class level constants
    static let productionURL = "YourProductionURL"
    static let demoURL = "YourDemoURL"

    //Class level variable
    var apiURL : String!

    //Static factory methods
    static func newProductionInstance() -> YourClass {
        return YourClass(with : YourClass.productionURL)
    }

    static func newDemoInstance() -> YourClass {
        return YourClass(with : YourClass.demoURL)
    }

    // Init method
    convenience init(with baseURLString : String) {
        self.init()
        self.apiURL = baseURLString

        //Calling
        let yourObject : YourClass = YourClass.newDemoInstance()
    }
}
```

Comment: *with, it should start with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

The best option to make instance type in objective-c that works in objective-c and Swift you should use **"default"** keyword. This keyword has been used in the standard libraries of Apple. For example NSNotificationCenter.default or NSFileManager.default. To declare it in the .h file you should write

```
+(instancetype) default;
```

and in your .m file

```
static YOUR_CLASS_NAME *instance = nil;

+(instancetype) default {
if instance == nil { instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];}
return instance;
}
```